# Inquisitors bane usage

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, inquisitor

The inquisitors [bane](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Classes/base-Classes/inquisitor/#TOC-Bane-Su-) ability confuses me as theres the way I feel it is meant to work (as thought by this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/8069/23058)) and the way it reads.

Bane

> At 5th level, an inquisitor can imbue one of her weapons with the bane weapon special ability as a swift action. She must select one creature type when she uses this ability (and a subtype if the creature type selected is humanoid or outsider). Once selected, the type can be changed as a swift action. This ability only functions while the inquisitor wields the weapon. If dropped or taken, the weapon resumes granting this ability if it is returned to the inquisitor before the duration expires. This ability lasts for a number of rounds per day equal to the inquisitor’s level. These rounds do not need to be consecutive.

So the way I feel it was meant to work is that the ability is limited to rounds per day based on inquisitor level which is how the linked answer also took it. But the way it reads to me is that you can use a swift action to activate Bane and it lasts for inquisitor levels, but doesnt have a usage amount.
The ability has a stated starting action, changing action, and duration (which is important and different from how other classes are worded). It does not mention stopping the action (likely free, but this is countered by the ability remaining in effect when not in possession) or that the number of times you can use the ability is limited.

Similar class abilities are the barbarians [rage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Barbarian/#TOC-Rage-Ex-), but it draws from a rage point pool, and you cant rage with an empty pool. A bard has their [performance](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/Core-classes/Bard/#TOC-Bardic-Performance), but its also built around a point pool. A magus [arcane poo](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Magus/#TOC-Arcane-Pool-Su-)l is the closest Ive found, as it has a stated activation and duration, but also draws from a pool.

There are other class abilities that are number of times per day per class level but none of them occur to me at the moment for comparison.

So RAW, does the inquisitor have a limit on the number of times per day they can activate Bane?

Comment: I have down voted this because the title does not clearly identify a question and the only question in your post is not relevant, because it does not matter how many times you can activate the ability but only the number of rounds you can use it per day, which is clearly identified by the class feature.

Comment: @Balacertar Im unaware of a site rule or requirement which says the question title has to be a question. Sure they normally are. Also, your comment partly resembles a answer which should not be in a comment. And clearly if I asked the question and supported it as I have, then there is room for doubt. The class feature was vague enough.

Comment: You are probably right, I will remove the down vote and provide an answer. Still, a more specific title could improve the options of your question being more visible and relevant. Also, the title talks about use while your question talks about activating, which seems misleading to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, their rounds per day is limited.

The last line of the portion of the ability you quote is your answer...

> This ability lasts for a number of **rounds per day** equal to the inquisitor’s level. These rounds do **not need to be consecutive**.

They are limited to (level) rounds *per day*, but the rounds do not need to be consecutive (meaning you don't have to take them all at once).

I agree that it's strange that they don't provide an action to maintain or dismiss the ability. However, there are similar abilities (usually auras, such as [Aura of Prescience](https://www.aonprd.com/SchoolDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Void)) that are worded similarly. It generally seems that such abilities merely are or are not maintained on their future turns.

Comment: I agree that its logical and reasonable that the ability is limited to inquisitor levels per day (not purely level), but the ability doesnt actually state that limitation anywhere.

Comment: @Fering bolded the portion that specifies that the rounds are counted by day. I'm not sure what more information you want than the words "rounds per day" means the number of rounds the ability is active on a given day.

Comment: Its worded as a duration, not as a usage

Comment: It also reads as once you start using it, it keeps going, or you can change, but you cant end. Since it doesnt say you can end it, would you also use it that way?

Comment: The inquisitor can activate the ability as often as she wants until it's been active for a number of rounds equal to her inquisitor level. After that, further attempts to activate the ability in the same day simply fail. There's no getting around the "rounds per day" limitation.

Comment: There are a number of other abilities worded the same way. None of them allow you to use the ability for that long repeatedly; per day means *per day*, not cumulative, not unlimited, not anything else.

Answer (score 1):

### No, there is no specific limit to the number of times you can activate the Bane class feature, but you are still bound by how long you can use it.

The class feature does not specify how many times per day you can imbue a weapon with the bane weapon quality. As such, if you had no duration limit, you could activate the feature as many times as you wished during a given day. In the hypothetical case, you had the ability to use a second swift action in a given round, you would be able to imbue another weapon, it is inferred (although admittedly not specified, because this cannot be done under general rules) that bane weapon quality in the second weapon would consume the inquisitor bane rounds.

Because the way bane works, what is relevant to the ability is for how long you can use it, not how many times you can activate it.